# CompareTo: Comparison method violates its general contract!

Tags: java, android, comparação

Achei muitas questões sobre este assunto, e tentei todas as sugestões que encontrei, contudo, o problema persistiu.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ai está meu problema:

Tenho uma lista de solicitações, esta lista é atualizada a partir de pull to refresh, e reordenada pelo `compareTo(Object o)` da interface `Comparable<>`.

Em um caso específico, o erro citado no titulo acontence, não consegui tratar o erro atrás do try/catch e não conseguir identificar o motivo.

Este é o código do meu método `compareTo`:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Notificacao another) {

    if ((another.getEndSLA() != null && another.getEndSLA().length() > 1) && 
            (getEndSLA() != null && getEndSLA().length() > 1)) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            Date date = format.parse(getEndSLA());
            Date dateAnother = format.parse(another.getEndSLA());

            return (int) (date.getTime() - dateAnother.getTime());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("EXCECAO", "EXCECAO LANCADA : " + e.getMessage() + " THIS : " + getEndSLA() + 
                    " ANOTHER : " + another.getEndSLA());
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro, o método `getEndSLA` deveria retornar um `Date`, ou pelo menos ter algum outro método que o faça, para melhorar a orientação a objetos. Não deveria ser responsabilidade do método de comparação ter que saber converter strings em datas representando SLAs.

Então, supondo que você não possa alterar o tipo de retorno do `getEndSLA`, recomendo a você acrescentar este daqui na classe `Notificacao`:

```java
public Date getEndSLADate() {
    String s = getEndSLA();
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) return null;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
            Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        return format.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Assim, dá para simplificar o seu método `compareTo`, e fica mais fácil de entendê-lo, analisá-lo e melhorá-lo:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Notificacao another) {
    Date a = getEndSLADate();
    Date b = another.getEndSLADate();

    if (a != null && b != null) return (int) (a.getTime() - b.getTime());
    return 0;
}
```

Bem mais simples né?

Aquele *cast* não é legal, pode resultar em algo bizarro quando as duas datas forem muito diferentes e alguns dos bits mais significativos forem cortados. Além disso, podemos comparar as datas diretamente, sem precisar do `getTime()`. Então vou arrumar isso:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Notificacao another) {
    Date a = getEndSLADate();
    Date b = another.getEndSLADate();

    if (a != null && b != null) return a.compareTo(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Claramente o método `compareTo` pode ser perfeitamente usado para ordenar as instâncias de `Notificacao` **que tiverem a data do fim do SLA**. O problema é quando elas não as têm: O `return 0` vai fazer elas parecerem ser equivalentes.

Vamos supor que tenhamos três objetos `Notificacao`. O objeto **A** com a data da segunda-feira, o **B** com a data da terça-feira e o **C** com a data `null`. Então, de acordo com o método `compareTo`:

> `A.compareTo(A)` produz 0, logo A = A
>   `B.compareTo(B)` produz 0, logo B = B
>   `C.compareTo(C)` produz 0, logo C = C
>   `A.compareTo(B)` produz -1, logo A < B
>   `B.compareTo(A)` produz +1, logo B > A
>   `A.compareTo(C)` produz 0, logo A = C
>   `C.compareTo(A)` produz 0, logo C = A
>   `B.compareTo(C)` produz 0, logo B = C
>   `C.compareTo(B)` produz 0, logo C = B

Estas quatro últimas linhas são o problema, pois se `A = C` e `C = B`, então concluiríamos que `A = B`. Mas não, pois `A < B`. Ou seja, o seu método `compareTo` é incoerente, e por isso ele produz resultados estranhos e/ou incorretos. **É aqui que o contrato do `compareTo` está sendo violado.**

A solução é fazer os elementos com data `null` virem ou todos antes ou todos depois dos que tem datas. Vou colocar como todos antes:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Notificacao another) {
    Date a = getEndSLADate();
    Date b = another.getEndSLADate();

    if (a == null && b == null) return 0;
    if (a == null) return -1;
    if (b == null) return 1;
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

E agora temos isso:

> `A.compareTo(C)` produz +1, logo A > C
>   `C.compareTo(A)` produz -1, logo C < A
>   `B.compareTo(C)` produz +1, logo B > C
>   `C.compareTo(B)` produz -1, logo C < B

E finalmente temos que `C < A < B`, e não há nenhuma incoerência no seu `compareTo`.

Answer (score 9):

Segundo a [documentação da interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (em tradução livre):

> A implementação deve ainda garantir que a relação seja transitiva: `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)` implica que `x.compareTo(z)>0`.

Agora considere os seguintes objetos hipotéticos:

```
Objeto  | getEndSLA()
--------|------------
  A     |     2
  B     |     1
  C     |     null
```

Seu comparador retornaria os seguintes valores:

```
A.compareTo(B) === 1
B.compareTo(C) === 0
A.compareTo(C) === 0
```

`A` é maior que `B`, e `B` é igual a `C`. Só que `A` também é igual a `C`. Por silogismo, se `A > B` e `B = C`, então `A > C`. Portanto seu código está quebrando essa lógica, que é exigida de quem implementa a interface. E é isso que a mensagem de erro está dizendo.

---

**Referência** [*In java, What do the return values of Comparable.compareTo mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767090/in-java-what-do-the-return-values-of-comparable-compareto-mean)