# Modificação concorrente em lista pode causar "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"?

Tags: java, exceção, multithreading

Tenho um programa com múltiplos threads que fazem modificações concorrentes em uma lista não sincronizada (por decisão ruim de design).

Às vezes, de forma aparentemente imprevisível, eu recebo `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` referente ao método `compareTo`, quando invocado um `sort` na lista.

Lendo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) e usando o código teste abaixo com exatamente os mesmos métodos `equals` e `compareTo`, concluo que a comparação está de acordo com o contrato; pois não consegui reproduzir a `IllegalArgumentException`.

---

Depois que sincronizei a lista (com `Collections.synchronizedList`) e toda parte do código que usa (ou modifica) a lista, não recebi mais a `IllegalArgumentException` (por enquanto).

Suponho que a causa do problema fosse a modificação concorrente da lista. Se sim, porque eu recebi `IllegalArgumentException` e não `NullPointerException` ou `ConcurrentModificationException`?

---

## Código teste (que não acontece exception alguma):

### Classe Pai:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Pai implements Comparable<Pai> {
    private static AtomicInteger contador = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private Integer indice;

    protected Integer ordem = 0;

    private String nome;

    private static List <Pai> familia;

    public Pai(String nome) {
        this.indice = contador.incrementAndGet();
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o != null && o instanceof Pai && this != null){
            return (this.indice == ((Pai) o).indice);
        }
        else {
            return false;       
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pai o){
        if (this != null && o != null)
            return (this.ordem - o.ordem);
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public String qualNome(){
        return this.nome;
    }

    public static void adicionarFilhos(){
        familia.add(new FilhoTres("3"));
        familia.add(new FilhoDois("2"));
        familia.add(new FilhoUm("1"));
        familia.add(new FilhoTres("3"));
        familia.add(new FilhoUm("1"));
        familia.add(new FilhoUm("1"));
        familia.add(new FilhoDois("2"));
        familia.add(new FilhoTres("3"));
        familia.add(new FilhoUm("1"));
        familia.add(new FilhoDois("2"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        familia = new ArrayList<Pai>();

        int i = 0;

        while (i < 1000){
            i++;

            familia.remove(5);

            Collections.sort(familia);

            familia.remove(2);

            Collections.sort(familia);
        }

        System.out.println("fim");
    }

}
```

### Filhos:

```
public class FilhoUm  extends Pai {

    public FilhoUm(String nome){
        super(nome);
        this.ordem = 1;
    }

}

public class FilhoDois extends Pai {

    public FilhoDois(String nome){
        super(nome);
        this.ordem = 2;
    }
}

public class FilhoTres extends Pai {

    public FilhoTres(String nome){
        super(nome);
        this.ordem = 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pode ter a ver com concorrência ou não. Pelo que é falado no SO em inglês a causa imediata parece ser que o contrato do `Comparator` não está sendo cumprido (um exemplo é quando ele não satisfaz a propriedade de transitividade). De acordo com [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20236925/2241463) o método `Arrays.sort()` que é usado por `Collections.sort()` mudou a implementação no Java 7 e agora lança uma `IllegalArgumentException` caso detecte que um `Comparator` violou o contrato que se espera dele.

Comment: Eu tenho dúvidas que só usar o `synchronizedList()` resolva o problema. O `sort()` trabalha movendo elementos da lista de lugar e embora essas operações de inserção e remoção agora sejam atômicas, pode se introduzir entre elas durante o `sort` uma inserção de elemento feita pelo seu código. O ideal é que o acesso à lista inteira durante toda a operação de `sort()` seja atômico (captou a diferença?).

Comment: Relevante, mas pelo que você descreve, não é isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44045/132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os seus métodos `compareTo`, `equals` e `hashCode` estão violando os seus contratos geral sim. Vamos analisá-los começando pelo `compareTo`:

## Método `compareTo`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pai o){
    if (this != null && o != null)
        return (this.ordem - o.ordem);
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

A expressão `this != null` é sempre verdadeira, pois não há forma possível para que o objeto `this` seja `null`. Portanto, ele se reduz a isso:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pai o) {
    if (o != null) return this.ordem - o.ordem;
    return 0;
}
```

Observe o `return 0`. Ele só é possível se o valor do `o` for `null`. Entretanto, eis o que consta no [javadoc da interface `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Note that `null` is not an instance of any class, and `e.compareTo(null)` should throw a `NullPointerException`

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Note que `null` não é uma instância de nenhuma classe, e que `e.compareTo(null)` deveria lançar um `NullPointerException`

Ou seja, dá para simplificar o seu `compareTo` para ficar assim:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Pai o) {
    return this.ordem - o.ordem;
}
```

## Método `equals`

Agora vamos ver o `equals`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o != null && o instanceof Pai && this != null){
        return (this.indice == ((Pai) o).indice);
    }
    else {
        return false;       
    }
}
```

A subexpressão `this != null` sempre é verdadeira, e portanto pode ser eliminada (não há como o `this` ser `null`). Além disso, se `o != null` for falso, então `o instanceof Pai` também será falso, e portanto o `o != null` é desnecessário e redundante. Assim sendo, o seu método `equals` se reduz a isso:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Pai) {
        return this.indice == ((Pai) o).indice;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Que por sua vez pode ser simplificado nisso:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Pai && this.indice == ((Pai) o).indice;
}
```

Entretanto, noto que o campo `indice` é do tipo `Integer`, e não `int`. Comparar dois objetos do tipo `Integer` usando o operador `==` é tão problemático quanto comparar `String`s usando o `==`, e pode resultar em surpresas desagradáveis. Por exemplo:

```
Integer a = new Integer(777);
Integer b = new Integer(777);
System.out.println(a == b);    // Escreve "false".
```

Assim sendo, assim ficará o seu `equals`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Pai && Objects.equals(this.indice, ((Pai) o).indice);
}
```

Ainda há mais um porém... A classe `Pai` tem subclasses. E nunca é boa ideia ter objetos de classes diferentes que possam ser iguais. Como esse método `equals` será herdado por todas as subclasses, teremos que seria possível que dois objetos de classes diferentes (mas ambos subclasses de `Pai`) seriam considerados iguais por terem os mesmos valores no campo `indice`. Assim sendo, essa seria uma implementação melhor para o seu `equals`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null
            && o.getClass() == this.getClass()
            && Objects.equals(this.indice, ((Pai) o).indice);
}
```

## Método `hashCode`

E agora o seu método `hashCode`. Bem... **Você não implementou o `hashCode`!** Ocorre que ele é fundamental, porque o `equals` o exige, conforme descrito no [javadoc do método `equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Note que é geralmente necessário sobreescrever o método `hashCode` sempre que este método for sobreescrito, de forma a manter o contrato geral para o método `hashCode`, que especifica que objetos iguais devem ter códigos hash iguais.

E olhando no [javadoc do método `hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Se dois objetos forem iguais de acordo com o método `equals(Object)`, então chamar o método `hashCode` em cada um desses dois objetos deve produzir o mesmo resultado inteiro.

Uma implementação bem simples para o seu método `hashCode` que funcione em conjunto com o `equals` e com o `compareTo` seria isso:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return indice == null ? 0 : indice;
}
```

## `compareTo` consistente com `equals`

Por fim, espera-se que se `a` e `b` são dois elementos iguais (ou seja `a.equals(b)` é verdadeiro), então espera-se que `a.compareTo(b)` seja zero. Entretanto, isso não ocorre no seu código. Embora o `Comparator` permita isso, ele recomenda fortemente contra:

> The natural ordering for a class `C` is said to be consistent with `equals` if and only if `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every `e1` and `e2` of class `C`.
>   [...]
>   It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with `equals`.

Que traduzindo para o português:

> A ordenação natural de uma classe `C` é dita ser consistente com o `equals` se e somente se `e1.compareTo(e2) == 0` tiver o mesmo valor boolean que `e1.equals(e2)` para cada `e1` e `e2` da classe `C`.
>   [...]
>   É fortemente recomendado (apesar de não requerido) que ordenações naturais sejam consistente com o `equals`.

Uma vez que você ordena usando o campo `ordem` e verifica a igualdade usando o campo `indice`, então a sua ordenação não é consistente com o `equals`.

Observo que no seu código, você parece nunca definir um valor para o campo `indice`, e portanto acho que o que você queria mesmo era verificar a igualdade por meio do campo `ordem`. Se for isso, então você apagaria o campo `indice` e esses seriam o seu `equals` e o seu `hashCode`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null
            && o.getClass() == this.getClass()
            && Objects.equals(this.ordem, ((Pai) o).ordem);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return ordem == null ? 0 : ordem;
}
```

Se você realmente quiser usar o `indice` para alguma finalidade alheia a ordenação, então eu recomendo que você defina que dois objetos são iguais quando os campos `indice` e `ordem` forem iguais, e portanto o seu `equals` e `hashCode` ficariam assim:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null
            && o.getClass() == this.getClass()
            && Objects.equals(this.indice, ((Pai) o).indice)
            && Objects.equals(this.ordem, ((Pai) o).ordem);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(indice, ordem);
}
```

Ainda há mais um problema, o seu `compareTo` vai dar um `NullPointerException` indesejado quando o campo `ordem` de algum dos objetos for `null`.

Entretanto, talvez você prefira colocar os campos `ordem` e `indice` como `int`, e neste caso, embora você possa substituir o uso do `Objects.equals` do seu método `equals` de volta para o `==`, ele vai continuar a funcionar se utilizar `Objects.equals`.

Com tudo isso, você deixará o seu `compareTo` consistente com o `equals` e não quebrará o contrato de nenhum dos métodos `compareTo`, `equals` ou `hashCode`.

Comment: Completa. Só faltou sugerir a utilização de `getters` e `setters`, não?

Comment: @GustavoCinque O que o uso de getters e setters tem a ver com isso? Os métodos `equals`, `hashCode` e `compareTo` não deveriam alterar o estado de nenhum objeto, e portanto não tem porque usar setters. O fato desses métodos acessarem os campos diretamente ao invés de fazerem isso por meio de getters não muda o resultado em nada que seja relacionado a esta questão. Quanto ao debate de utilizar-se o acesso direto aos campos ou acessá-los apenas por meio de getters, há opiniões para os dois lados, mas isso já foge do contexto e do objetivo tanto da pergunta quanto dessa resposta.